# HTML: how refresh information in <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have div with link to php file. In 'test.php' contains connection to DB and table with result.

```
require ('test.php');
```

How refresh context every 30 sec ????

Comment: No clear enough. Please add more information.

Comment: using ajax perhaps..

Comment: Your question is too broad. It's depends on the context and can be achieved by many ways. Websockets, Ajax...

Comment: Lacks of information, you should post your html structure to make it more clearer, And tell us what data are trying to poll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.post('test.php', { someParameter: 'someValue' }, function(data){
      $('#my-container').html(data);
    });
  }, 30000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this `div` you are talking about is in `index.php` and you already have jQuery in `index.php`.

index.php

```
<div id="refreshMe"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(
  function(){ $.get("test.php", function(data){$("#refreshMe").html(data);}); }, 
30000);
</script>
```

This should pretty much achieve what you want.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your script.

Comment: You can fix that right?

Comment: Well not quiet syntax error but you misspelled `<script>`.